# Spring cloud gateway load balancing

Tags: apache-camel, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using Spring Cloud Gateway [JavaDsl] as our API Gateway.  For the proxies we have multiple microservices [running on different ip:port] as target's.  Would like to know either we can configure multiple targets to spring cloud gateway proxies, similar to apache camel load balancer eip.

camel.apache.org/manual/latest/loadBalance-eip.html

We are looking for software load balancing with in spring cloud gateway [similar to netflix/apache-camel] instead of another dedicated LB.

Answer (score 0):

Able to get Spring Cloud Gateway load balanced Route working using spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon. However when one of the server instance is down, load-balancing-fails. Code Snippets below.

Version :

spring-cloud-gateway :  2.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

> **Gateway Route**

```
.route(
        r ->
            r.path("/res/security/")
            .filters( f -> f
                    .preserveHostHeader()
                    .rewritePath("/res/security/", "/targetContext/security/")
                    .filter(new LoggingFilter()) 
                    .uri("lb://target-service1-endpoints")
            )
```

> **application.yml**

```
ribbon:
  eureka:
   enabled: false


target-service1-endpoints:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: 172.xx.xx.s1:80, 172.xx.xx.s2:80
    ServerListRefreshInterval: 1000 
    retryableStatusCodes: 404, 500 
    MaxAutoRetriesNextServer: 1

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from Spring Cloud Team.

What you've described, indeed, happens. However, it is not gateway-specific. If you just use Ribbon in a Spring Cloud project with listOfServers, the same thing will happen. This is because, unlike for eureka, the IPing for non-discovery-service scenario is not instrumented (a DummyPing instance is used).

You could probably change this behaviour by providing your own IPing, IRule or ServerListFilter implementation and overriding the setup we provide in the autoconfiguration in this way.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1482